# Save Cancel button event handler is not working in Radscheduler advance insert form

Tags: asp.net, telerik

In my application I have a radschedular , when creating a new appointment I am opening in advance mode by specifying **StartInsertingInAdvancedForm="True"**

### My code is given below

.aspx

```
<telerik:RadScheduler RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="rs_course_schedule" CustomAttributeNames="Completed" 
                StartInsertingInAdvancedForm="True" StartEditingInAdvancedForm="True"
                FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" LastDayOfWeek="Friday" Reminders-Enabled="true" SelectedView="WeekView"
                RowHeight="30px" AppointmentStyleMode="Simple" OnAppointmentDataBound="RadScheduler1_AppointmentDataBound" 
                OnAppointmentCommand="rs_course_schedule_OnAppointmentCommand"
                OnAppointmentCreated="RadScheduler1_AppointmentCreated" OverflowBehavior="Auto" Skin="Web20" 
                OnAppointmentInsert="rs_course_schedule_OnAppointmentInsert">
                <AdvancedForm Modal="true"></AdvancedForm>
                <AppointmentTemplate>
                    <div class="appointmentHeader">
                        <asp:Panel ID="RecurrencePanel" CssClass="rsAptRecurrence" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="RecurrenceExceptionPanel" CssClass="rsAptRecurrenceException" runat="server"
                            Visible="false">
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="ReminderPanel" CssClass="rsAptReminder" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <%#Eval("Subject") %>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Assigned to: <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="UserLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.Appointment.Resources.GetResourceByType("Faculty") == null ? "None" : Container.Appointment.Resources.GetResourceByType("Faculty").Text %>'></asp:Label>
                        </strong>
                        <br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CompletedStatusCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Completed? " TextAlign="Left"
                            Checked='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Container.Appointment.Attributes["Completed"]) && Boolean.Parse(Container.Appointment.Attributes["Completed"]) %>'
                            AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CompletedStatusCheckBox_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                    </div>
                </AppointmentTemplate>
                <ResourceStyles>
                    <telerik:ResourceStyleMapping Type="Faculty" Key="1" BackColor="red"></telerik:ResourceStyleMapping>
                    <telerik:ResourceStyleMapping Type="Faculty" Key="2" BackColor="Pink"></telerik:ResourceStyleMapping>
                    <telerik:ResourceStyleMapping Type="Faculty" Key="3" BackColor="OrangeRed"></telerik:ResourceStyleMapping>
                </ResourceStyles>
            </telerik:RadScheduler>
```

in code behind

```
    public partial class Schedule : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        #region Object Instantiation
        readonly BEL_LMS _objLms = new BEL_LMS();
        readonly BL_LMS _blLms = new BL_LMS();
        #endregion
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateSchedular();
                AddTeachers();
                SetDate();
            }
        }

        private void AddTeachers()
        {
            _objLms.ActivityId = Session["activity_id"].ToString();
            DataTable dtFaculty =  _blLms.AssignedFaculty(_objLms);
            ResourceType resources = new ResourceType("Faculty");
            if (dtFaculty.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                resources.DataSource = dtFaculty;
                resources.KeyField = "userid";
                resources.TextField = "acct_name";
                resources.ForeignKeyField = "UserId";
                rs_course_schedule.ResourceTypes.Add(resources);
            }
        }

        private void SetDate()
        {
            rs_course_schedule.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void PopulateSchedular()
        {
            _objLms.Flag = "fetch";
            _objLms.ActivityId = "11";
            DataTable dtTable = _blLms.FetchScheduleForCourse(_objLms);
            if (dtTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                rs_course_schedule.DataKeyField = "ID";
                rs_course_schedule.DataStartField = "Start";
                rs_course_schedule.DataEndField = "End";
                rs_course_schedule.DataSubjectField = "Subject";
                rs_course_schedule.DataDescriptionField = "Description";
                //rs_course_schedule.DataReminderField = "Reminder";
                rs_course_schedule.DataSource = dtTable;
                rs_course_schedule.DataBind();

            }
        }


        protected void CompletedStatusCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox CompletedStatusCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
            //Find the appointment object to directly interact with it
            SchedulerAppointmentContainer appContainer = (SchedulerAppointmentContainer)CompletedStatusCheckBox.Parent;
            Appointment appointment = appContainer.Appointment;
            _objLms.ActivityId = appointment.ID.ToString();
            _objLms.Flag = "update";
            int affectedRow = _blLms.UpdateCourse(_objLms); // update checkbox data for that particular schedule
            rs_course_schedule.Rebind();
        }

        protected void RadScheduler1_AppointmentDataBound(object sender, SchedulerEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Appointment.Attributes["Completed"] == "True")
            {
                e.Appointment.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }

        protected void RadScheduler1_AppointmentCreated(object sender, AppointmentCreatedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void rs_course_schedule_OnAppointmentInsert(object sender, AppointmentInsertEventArgs e)
        {
            SchedulerDataSource.InsertParameters["End"].DefaultValue = e.Appointment.End.ToString();
            SchedulerDataSource.InsertParameters["Start"].DefaultValue = e.Appointment.Start.ToString();
            SchedulerDataSource.InsertParameters["Subject"].DefaultValue = e.Appointment.Start.ToString();
            SchedulerDataSource.InsertParameters["Description"].DefaultValue = e.Appointment.Description;
            SchedulerDataSource.InsertParameters["CourseID"].DefaultValue = "1";
            //SchedulerDataSource.InsertParameters["User"].DefaultVal;
        }


        protected void rs_course_schedule_OnAppointmentCommand(object sender, AppointmentCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = e.CommandName;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I am trying to insert a new appointment this form is opening 
[image]

But in Save and Cancel button click is not occurring..

How I can solve this issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not occurring"?  I assume you set a breakpoint in the code behind and it never hits that function?  Is it posting anything back (aka does any code behind function get called)?  Is the edit form closing?  Are you seeing any errors in the browser developer console or network tabs?  Please provide more information.

Comment: @chambo which server side event will fire if I click on either Save or Cancel button?

Comment: Depends on how your page is setup.  I would expect the OnAppointmentCreated and/or the OnAppointmentInsert events to be raised if you are inserting a new appointment.  If the page is not Ajaxed then the PageLoad would likely fire again too.  I'd put breakpoints everywhere and see if  you hit anything.  If you are then the control is at least posting back and the problem is in your code behind.  If nothing is getting back to the server side then your issue is with the control or the page markup.

Comment: @chambo on simple insert form break point gets hit on  protected void rs_course_schedule_OnAppointmentInsert(object sender, AppointmentInsertEventArgs e)
        {}. But on advance edit form it does't..

Comment: That's odd - are you seeing any errors in the developer tools console when using the advanced form?  What happens when you click the button on the advanced form?  anything? please describe in detail.

Comment: @chambo  add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" /> in web.config solved my problem . Thanks for your helps.

Comment: cheers! - happy coding!

Comment: @chambo Thanks man !